# Providing RS-485 ground when no pin is provided

Tags: rs485

I have a PC with an RS-232 to RS-485 converter controlling (@ 9600 baud) a large piece of HVAC equipment in an adjacent utility room, <50' away.  We are adding two more of these pieces of equipment, each about 10' from the first unit, and would like to add them to the RS-485 bus.  Everything I've read says that using a 3rd ground conductor is mandatory, and that just wiring the differential pair can fry the tranceivers... but the manufacturer of this equipment doesn't even  provide for a signal ground.  RS-485 is connected through a DB9 connector, with only 2 pins (A/B lines) connected.  Note this is an industrial setting, and the equipment is powered through large, 3 phase pin-and-sleeve connectors.  Should I:

- Just wire to the two signal lines, assuming ground potential difference isn't an issue at this scale, and/or that the mfg. has taken steps to protect their equipment;
- Tie signal ground and shield together at the PC side, and connect the shield to the chassis at the equipment side;
- Connect the signal ground to the GND pin in the **RS-232** connector the equipment *also* has, assuming the -232 and -485 transceivers use the same reference;
- Something else?

Thank you!

Comment: Speak to the supplier and ask them.

Comment: The case of the DB9 is often a ground.

Comment: It's possible the HVAC equipment has isolated RS485 transceivers so you won't have a problem. But you need to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: @SteveG Signal ground is still mandatory with RS-485 or other unbalanced differential signalling.

Comment: Option 4: ask for a refund. There's so many crappy converters out there.

Comment: Buy an isolated USB - RS485 converter, don't fry your PC. I do use a cheap one YN tech 6 in 1 isolated converter, but other cheaper one is also good I think YN485I (FT232RL + ADM2587). You connect the GND to earth or you may leave it floating, assuming you have an isolated converter.